# define a array list usable in both mapper and reducer

Tags: hadoop, arraylist, mapreduce

In my hadoop code I need to define a Arraylist that both Mapper and Reducer can access it. for other variables i can use parameters. but i do not know about arrayList! how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array of strings as a parameter using conf.setStrings(name, values...)

```
Configuration conf = getConf();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
conf.setStrings("my-array-list", arr);
```

In the setup functions of the reducer and mapper, you can recreate the ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> list = 
    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(conf.getStrings("my-array-list")));
```

Comment: I have ArrayList<IntArrayList>.  how can I pass this array?